# What kind of mathematics is common in quantum computing?

Tags: mathematics

From what I have seen so far, there is a lot of linear algebra. Curious what other kinds of maths are used in QC & the specific fields in which they are most predominately invoked.

Comment: This question is really, really broad. As the current answer shows, pretty much any and all maths can be used in QC.

Comment: @heather I did not realize that when asking. I think it serves as a good reference for the future tho.

Comment: https://abstrusegoose.com/105

Comment: How can you edit an existing question such as to completely reverse its meaning?  This makes all answers void!

Comment: As @NorbertScuch's comment above, it's not a great idea to edit a question to such an extent after it has a valid answer as this invalidates the answer, so I'm reverting the edit. Normally, I'd say to ask a separate question but in this case, it would still be too broad/off-topic by virtue of essentially being a 'shopping list question', so you'd be better off asking that sort of thing in [chat], if there's someone there willing to answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Calculus (e.g. $\int |\psi(x)|^2dx = 1$ )
- Differential Equations (e.g. Schroedinger equation)
- Complex analysis
- Statistics/Probability theory
- Stochastics (especially in studying open quantum systems)
- Information theory
- Topology (e.g. [topological quantum computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_quantum_computer))
- Group theory (e.g. in stabilizer codes)
- Representation theory (e.g. in stabilizer codes)
- Graph theory (e.g. [graph state quantum computing](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0509209))
- Functional analysis (e.g. [Quantum states are unit vectors... with respect to which norm?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2729/quantum-states-are-unit-vectors-with-respect-to-which-norm))
- Algebraic geometry (e.g. [for factoring numbers using quantum annealing](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep43048))
- Discrete optimization (e.g. [for factoring numbers using quantum annealing](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.6758) and [also](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.08061).)
- Optimal control theory (here's a review on [quantum optimal control theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.1883))
- Game theory (for quantum games)
- Boolean algebra (see this book on [Boolean functions and quantum mechanics](https://github.com/k-local-quadratization/review/blob/master/k-local-review.pdf))
- Coding theory (e.g. Quantum Error Correcting codes)
- Number theory (e.g. Shor's algorithm)
- Category theory (e.g. [What is the use of Categorical quantum mechanics?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/what-is-the-use-of-categorical-quantum-mechanics))
- Differential geometry (for quantum information theorists working on quantum gravity)
- Formal Language Theory (in studying QC as a computation model)
- **Amazingly**, I've even seen [fractional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) come up for sub-Ohmic baths (s=1/2 in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1205.4651.pdf))

  ---
- Basically any area of mathematics because we would like to make quantum algorithms to do things more efficiently, regardless of the mathematical field. For example "semi-definite programming" could be added to the list, because quantum algorithms for semi-definite programming is a very active current area of research.

  ---
- <sup>A better question might be "is there any area of mathematics for which you cannot see any possible connection to quantum computing?"</sup>

Comment: is there any area of mathematics for which *you* cannot see any possible connection to qc?

Comment: I've been thinking about it since seeing your question!

Comment: I can't think of a lot of examples where vector calculus comes up. But they're the heart of Maxwell's equations, which you'd use if you're implementing an optical quantum computer.